# How is Spring Security ACL different from Authorization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was with the idea that spring roles based access control is everything it takes to secure resources based on the roles a user is granted. Now I see there is something like ACL too with spring. So just want to understand if ACL is same as role based authorization. If not, does it complement role based authorization or if these two are exclusive or just entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Roles and ACL:s are both related to authorization. The difference is on which level they do access control.

- **Roles** are *per application*. For example a SYSADMIN role can give access to edit all the users in the system. Roles are sometimes called *authorities* in Spring Security, technically roles are a subset of authorities.
- **ACLs** (Access Control Lists) are *per domain object*. For example, consider an application where files can be uploaded. User A should be allowed to read File X and User B should be allowed to read File Y. This is solved by having one ACL for file X and one for file Y. There can also be different *permissions*; e.g. User C should be able to read and change file X but only read file Y.

Roles are usually static while ACL:s are dynamically added when resources are created in the system.

Comment: cool... that's wonderful explanation on ACL. But why would a spring application have to worry about a domain object. That's an entity external to Spring App ( not like a /admin path which is part of the app and roles define users of which role (admins, managers...) have access to this path and similarly with spring's method level access.). How does spring support ACL's, does it work with some per defined domain. Like ??? Could you give a production/real use case of ACL.

Comment: @samshers Spring Security includes a JDBC implementation of ACLs. Per default you can use any class with a `Long id` property as domain class. But can be customized so any class with a unique key can be a domain class. When working with JPA, `@Entity` classes are typical domain classes.